# Webdav (Sabredav) Server Configuration

Tags: apache, webdav, typo3

for a customer website I use Sabredav within a Typo3 Extension (webdav, by Kay Strobach). This
extension, "activates" sabredav when a user enters the following URL:

http://mycustomersite.com/index.php/dav

I can connect with GoodSync with no problems, everything works fine.
Now, I should go a step further. The address

data.mycustomersite.com

should "point" to the address above. Simple redirect seems not to
work, since I get errors.

I know, that this can be solved by mod_rewrite. Unfortunately I have
only a little knowledge of apache...

What exactly should I have to write in order to achieve this? And
where?

Thank you very much in advance.

Davide

Answer (score 0):

You should write to an official [typo3 mailing list](http://lists.typo3.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/typo3-english), where e.g. Kay is reading and answering ;-)